# GAN generator for image size 224X224

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network, image-size, synthetic

i want to generate synthetic image of size 224x224 using gan generator. but i dont understand how to design dcgan generator specific image size using 2d transpose convolution. kindly help

TensorFlow Gan code for DCGAN I tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, could you provide the dataset your working on or if you could put the part of the Generator code where you are facing issues